# Reykjavík being written to div with strange characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html

```
<div class="ui-widget" style="margin-top: 1em; font-family: Arial">
   Selected:
<div id="locationLog" style="height: 100px; width: 200px; overflow: auto;" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="HiddenLocations" id="HiddenLocation" />
```

I then have some code that runs each time the page loads to add some text into the `locationLog` div.

```
@if (Model.SearchCriteria != null && Model.SearchCriteria.Locations != null)
{
   foreach (string t in @Model.SearchCriteria.Locations)
   {
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $("<div/>").text('@t').appendTo("#locationLog");
         $("<br/>").text("").appendTo("#locationLog");
         $("#locationLog").scrollTop(0);

         selectedLocations = $('#locationLog' + ' div').map(function () {
            return $(this).text();
         }).get();

         $('input[name=HiddenLocations]').val(selectedLocations); 
      </script>
   }
}
```

Now, this code works well when I have text such as 'London' but when I have 'Reykjavík', this get's written as '`Reykjav&#237;k`'.  How can I write out the correct text?

Comment: What is the "correct text"? What is the expected result?

Comment: The correct text should be 'Reykjavík'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring utf-8 charset in your document

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

**EDIT:**
Try this:

```
function htmlDecode(input){
  var e = document.createElement('div');
  e.innerHTML = input;
  return e.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

and use it here:

```
selectedLocations = $('#locationLog' + ' div').map(function () {
   return htmlDecode($(this).text());
}).get();
```

Source: [Unescape HTML entities in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript)

Comment: I think it's this line that needs to be changed though. $("<div/>").text('@t').appendTo("#locationLog");

Comment: ow, then you should change the line to something like:
$("#locationLog").append(htmlDecode($("<div/>").text('@t')));

Comment: This line did not work.  Should it not be $("<div/>").text(htmlDecode('@t')).appendTo("#locationLog");